# Useful resources to start to learn Gatling

Tags: performance, load-testing

Gatling: Performance testing tool

I am looking for Gatling tutorials, but I could not find any interesting courses or tutorial to follow. I would like to find some good value for time resources, URLs or any other recommendations to help me learn to use Gatling.

Comment: How would you define "best"? What research have you done? Please read https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - the expectation on this site is that you've "thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question", but the question, as currently worded, is essentially asking people to do the research for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I learn Gatling using the resources I found online and experimentation. Just google "Gatling tutorial", there are plenty of links to pages showing Gatling basics, many focus on different aspects so it's useful to read a number of them. I 
always found official resource helpful, [The Gatling documentation 3.0](https://gatling.io/docs/3.0/) is pretty good as well, they also have an [Advanced Tutorial](https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/) covering more stuff. Gatling is open source, so you can always browse the source if you need more clarity on how something works.

For High-Level understanding, you may start with video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUPTaPms210